# What values of x would make T NOT onto?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, linear-transformations

A linear transformation T : R3 → R4 has associated matrix

A = \begin{bmatrix}x&0&x+1&0\\0&x+8&0&x+8\\x-1&0&x+10&0\end{bmatrix}

which depends on some number x. There is at least one value of x such that T is not onto. I know that -8 is one of them because of the second row, but I was told that there is another value I should be looking for. Would appreciate a tip in the right direction!

Comment: That's the matrix of a linear map from $\mathbb{R}^4$ into $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have a matrix with $n$ rows and $m$ columns, with $m>n$, then it's the matrix of a surjective linear map if and only if, when you remove any $m-n$ columns, the determinant of the remaining matrix is not $0$. In your case:

- if you remove the fourth column, the determinant is $10x^2+81x+8$;
- if you remove the third column, the determinant is $0$;
- if you remove the second column, the determinant is $-10x^2-81x-8$;
- if you remove the first column, the determinant is $0$.

Therefore, $T$ is not onto if and only if $10x^2+81x+8=0$, that is, if and only if $x=-8$ or $x=-\frac1{10}$.

Comment: Thank you so much! I actually only learned to visually check that when x=-8, row 2 would be [0 0 0 0] thus not onto since not every row has a pivot. This method through determinants was the algebraic way I needed!